# Json deserialization using jackson for java.lang.object returns java.lang.ArrayList

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, jackson-databind

I am having a Java class as following with a generic method.

```
public final class Message {

    private final MessageHeader header;
    private final Object body;

    @JsonCreator
    public <T> Message(@JsonProperty("header") MessageHeader header, @JsonProperty("body") T body) {
        this.header = header;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public MessageHeader getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public Object getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public <T> T getBody(Class<T> objectType) {
        if(objectType.isInstance(this.body)) {
            return objectType.cast(this.body);
        }
        throw new Exception("Message body is not of type "+objectType.toString());
    }
}
```

Using Jackson 2.8.4 for serializing and deserializing the object in JSON format using a mapper enabled with DefaultTyping (mapper.enableDefaultTyping()). Running into problems while trying to retrieve the message body part using generic version of getBody method. Getting object of type java.util.ArrayList instead of the actual object type passed. Any suggestions on what is missing mapper configuration or any other ?

Message.getBody is invoked as following.

```
DataSet data = getDataSet();
Message message = new Message(header,data);
...
DataSet data = message.getBody(DataSet.class);
```

Adding JSON that is giving problem.

```
{ 
  "header" : {
    "hostId" : "XYZ",
    "hostname" : "X-123456789",
    "systemType" : "ABC"
  },"
  "body" : [ "com.foo.DataSet", {
    "createTimestamp" : 1502859923155,
    "records" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ {
      "name" : "Running",
      "timestamp" : 1502859923162,
      "value" : true
    }, {
      "name" : "Command",
      "timestamp" : 1502859923162,
      "value" : false
    } ] ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you call the generic `getBody` ? Also have you considered making `Message` class generic ?

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis I have edited post the include the info asked. I didn't want to make Message generic to avoid multiple levels of generic objects as I collections a lot to move around Message and found it be hard.